# Bootstrap form value empty

Tags: python, forms, flask

I have the [following select form from bootstrap.org](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms) and customized to my needs but when I use request.form() the ouput is always empty:

HTML

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('addPOTM') }}">
      <div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto my-1">
          <label class="mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Add Player</label>
          <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            {% for rows in dropdown %}
            <option value="{{ rows.Name }}">{{ rows.Name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto my-1">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="newPOTM">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Python:

```
import sqlite3, logging
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, flash, redirect, jsonify
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort

@app.route('/potm')
def potm():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    dragdrop = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM POTM ORDER BY listorder ASC")
    dropdown = conn.execute('SELECT Name FROM alltime ORDER BY Name ASC').fetchall()
    return render_template('potm.html', dragdrop=dragdrop, dropdown=dropdown)

@app.route("/addPOTM",methods=["POST","GET"])
def addPOTM():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Name = request.form['newPOTM']
        print(Name)
    return redirect(url_for('potm'))
```

Feel like it is very simple and I already had it today but did not save it and now cant see what I did earlier today :( Need a break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the value of `newPOTM`:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
        Name = request.form['newPOTM']
        print(Name)
```

And your form submits it in a button element (with empty value):

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="newPOTM">Submit</button>
```

when you realy needs read the value of the select element. Simply add the correct `name` attribute to the select (and remove it from the `button`):

```html
<select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="newPOTM">
```

Comment: Ahh, I'm late @fk1.

Answer (score 0):

I added name="newPOTM" also to the line

`<select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">`

and it works